# apache2 handle subdomains and SSL

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, https, subdomain

I have this line in my mycooldomain.com.conf (apache2)

```
  Redirect permanent / https://mycooldomain.com
```

it redirects to https.
What I am trying to do is redirect subdomains to http while all domain requests go through https
for example:
mycooldomain.com/help will redirect to https://mycooldomain.com
while user.mycooldomain.com/blah will redirect to http://user.mycooldomain.com
right now subdomains are being sent to https as well

Answer (score 0):

Add a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} user.mycooldomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://user.mycooldomain.com/$1 [QSA, R=301, L]

Redirect permanent / https://mycooldomain.com
```